# Electron: How open browser upload file dialog attached in electron

Tags: html, electron

I found out that it used to work in version 2.0.2 and doesn't work in 3.0.2

I recently changed my electron environment to electron 3 and electron-builder, and now I have problem with upload file dialog window. Before changing the environment the file upload dialog was attached to my mainWindow, now it is detached and I can use the program when dialog is opened, and even if I click outside the dialog it goes back from the main window. I tried to use `dialog` feature of electron, which gives me the opportunity to attach file dialog, but it lacks performance, when I try to upload files more then 500-1000mb, I need to open them with fs.readFile or http get request and make them blob. Browser native file dialog do this for me and it works maybe 100 times faster then with fs. How can I attach native browser upload dialog to my main window?

Comment: how do you exactly use `dialog`? Dialog itself doesn't do any uploading, just allows you to select files. Action on files is up to you, so I don't understand how it "lacks performance". Show some code.

Comment: I read files with fs.read, and it reads 1GB files very slow, in spite of it native browser dialog does it in less then a second